# VHDL input is not a globally static

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity alu_1bit is
  port (
    i_OPERATION : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);  -- entrada de operação (controle de operação)
    i_INV_BIT   : in  std_logic;
    i_CARRY_IN  : in  std_logic;
    i_A         : in  std_logic;
    i_B         : in  std_logic;
    i_LESS      : in  std_logic;
    o_RESULT    : out std_logic;
    o_CARRY_OUT : out std_logic);
end alu_1bit;

architecture arch_1 of alu_1bit is
  component full_adder is
    port (
      i_CIN  : in  std_logic;
      i_DIN0 : in  std_logic;
      i_DIN1 : in  std_logic;
      o_DOUT : out std_logic;
      o_COUT : out std_logic);
  end component;

  component mux4 is
    port(i_SEL  : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
         i_DIN0 : in  std_logic;
         i_DIN1 : in  std_logic;
         i_DIN2 : in  std_logic;
         i_DIN3 : in  std_logic;
         o_DOUT : out std_logic);
  end component;

  signal w_B     : std_logic;
  signal w_C     : std_logic;
  signal w_D     : std_logic;
  signal w_OUTFA : std_logic;

begin
  w_B <= i_INV_BIT xor i_B;
  w_C <= i_A and i_B;
  w_D <= i_A or i_B;

  u_1 : full_adder port map (i_CIN  => i_CARRY_IN,
                             i_DIN0 => i_A,
                             i_DIN1 => w_B,
                             o_DOUT => w_OUTFA,
                             o_COUT => o_CARRY_OUT);

  u_2 : mux4 port map(i_SEL  => i_OPERATION,
                      i_DIN0 => w_C,
                      i_DIN1 => w_D,
                      i_DIN2 => w_OUTFA,
                      i_DIN3 => i_LESS,
                      o_DOUT => o_RESULT);

end arch_1;
```

I'm trying  to simulate this on Quartus ModelSim but is giving me the following error on ModelSim.

> Error: .../alu_1bit_msb.vhd(53): (vcom-1436) Actual expression (infix expression) of formal "i_DIN0" is not globally static.
>
> Error: .../alu_1bit_msb.vhd(54): (vcom-1436) Actual expression (infix expression) of formal "i_DIN1" is not globally static.

I've already removed the logic expression out of the port map of mux4, i used a signal do this...

Full addder code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity full_adder is
port (
    i_CIN : in std_logic;
    i_DIN0 : in std_logic; 
    i_DIN1 : in std_logic; 
    o_DOUT : out std_logic; 
    o_COUT : out std_logic); 
end full_adder;

architecture arch_1 of full_adder is
begin
    o_DOUT <= i_CIN xor i_DIN0 xor i_DIN1;
    o_COUT <= (i_CIN and i_DIN0) or
    (i_CIN and i_DIN1) or
    (i_DIN0 and i_DIN1);
end arch_1;
```

MUX4 code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux4 is
port (
    i_SEL : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 
    i_DIN0 : in std_logic;
    i_DIN1 : in std_logic;
    i_DIN2 : in std_logic; 
    i_DIN3 : in std_logic; 
    o_DOUT : out std_logic); 
end mux4;

architecture arch_1 of mux4 is
begin
    o_DOUT <= i_DIN0 when i_SEL = "00" else
          i_DIN1 when i_SEL = "01" else
          i_DIN2 when i_SEL = "10" else
          i_DIN3;
end arch_1;
```

alu32 code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;

entity alu_32bit is
port (
    i_OPERATION :   in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);       
    i_INV_BIT   :   in      std_logic;
    i_A         :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    i_B         :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    o_RESULT        :   out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    o_ZERO      :   out std_logic;
    o_OVERFLOW  :   out std_logic);
end alu_32bit;

architecture arch_1 of alu_32bit is
    component alu_1bit is
    port (
        i_OPERATION :   in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);        
        i_INV_BIT   :   in std_logic;
        i_CARRY_IN  :   in std_logic;
        i_A         :   in std_logic;
        i_B         :   in std_logic;
        i_LESS      : in std_logic;
        o_RESULT        :   out std_logic;
        o_CARRY_OUT :   out std_logic);
    end component;
    
    component alu_1bit_msb is
    port (
        i_OPERATION :   in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);        -- entrada de operação (controle de operação)
        i_INV_BIT   :   in std_logic;
        i_CARRY_IN  :   in std_logic;
        i_A         :   in std_logic;
        i_B         :   in std_logic;
        i_LESS      :   in std_logic;
        o_RESULT        :   out std_logic;
        o_SET       :   out std_logic;
        o_OVERFLOW  :   out std_logic);
    end component;
    
    signal w_RESULT : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal w_CARRY : std_logic_vector(30 downto 0);
    signal w_SET : std_logic;
    
begin
    o_RESULT <= w_RESULT;
    o_ZERO <= NOT (or_reduce(w_RESULT));
    
    u_0: alu_1bit port map (i_OPERATION => i_OPERATION,     
                                    i_INV_BIT   => i_INV_BIT,
                                    i_CARRY_IN  => i_INV_BIT,
                                    i_A         => i_A(0),
                                    i_B         => i_B(0),
                                    i_LESS      => w_SET,
                                    o_RESULT        => w_RESULT(0),
                                    o_CARRY_OUT => w_CARRY(0));
    
    f_0: for i in 1 to (30) generate
        u_1: alu_1bit port map (i_OPERATION => i_OPERATION,     
                                        i_INV_BIT   => i_INV_BIT,
                                        i_CARRY_IN  => w_CARRY(i-1),
                                        i_A         => i_A(i),
                                        i_B         => i_B(i),
                                        i_LESS      => '0',
                                        o_RESULT        => w_RESULT(i),
                                        o_CARRY_OUT => w_CARRY(i));
    end generate f_0;

    u_2: alu_1bit_msb port map (i_OPERATION => i_OPERATION,     
                     i_INV_BIT      => i_INV_BIT,
                                         i_CARRY_IN     => w_CARRY(30),
                                         i_A                => i_A(31),
                                         i_B                => i_B(31),
                                         i_LESS         => '0',
                                         o_RESULT           => w_RESULT(31),
                                         o_SET              => w_SET,
                                         o_OVERFLOW     => o_OVERFLOW);
end arch_1;
```

alu_1bit_msb code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity alu_1bit_msb is
port (
    i_OPERATION :   in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);        
    i_INV_BIT   :   in std_logic;
    i_CARRY_IN  :   in std_logic;
    i_A         :   in std_logic;
    i_B         :   in std_logic;
    i_LESS      :   in std_logic;
    o_RESULT        :   out std_logic;
    o_SET       :   out std_logic;
    o_OVERFLOW  :   out std_logic);
end alu_1bit_msb;

architecture arch_1 of alu_1bit_msb is
    component full_adder is
    port (
        i_CIN : in std_logic; 
        i_DIN0 : in std_logic; 
        i_DIN1 : in std_logic; 
        o_DOUT : out std_logic; 
        o_COUT : out std_logic); 
    end component;
    
    component mux4 is
    port(i_SEL : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 
          i_DIN0 : in std_logic; 
          i_DIN1 : in std_logic; 
          i_DIN2 : in std_logic; 
          i_DIN3 : in std_logic; 
          o_DOUT : out std_logic); 
    end component;
    
    signal w_B : std_logic;
    signal w_OUTFA : std_logic;
    signal w_COUT : std_logic;
    
begin
    w_B <= i_INV_BIT XOR i_B;
    o_SET <= w_OUTFA;
    o_OVERFLOW <= (w_COUT XOR i_CARRY_IN) AND i_OPERATION(1);
    
    u_1: full_adder port map (i_CIN => i_CARRY_IN,
                                      i_DIN0 => i_A,
                                      i_DIN1 => w_B,
                                      o_DOUT => w_OUTFA,
                                    o_COUT => w_COUT);
                                      
    u_2: mux4 port map(
                i_SEL => i_OPERATION,       
                            i_DIN0 => i_A AND i_B,  
                            i_DIN1 => i_A OR i_B,   
                            i_DIN2 => w_OUTFA,          
                          i_DIN3 => i_LESS,         
                            o_DOUT => o_RESULT);                                      
end arch_1;
```

Comment: In the shown code, the formal `i_DIN0` and `i_DIN1` have actual `i_A` and `w_B`, which compiles fine in my Altera ModelSim.  Are you sure that you compile the same code that you posted?   Maybe you have two versions of the code, where the other version has some expression with infix operators as actual ?

Comment: You're trying to say that i have 2 alu_1bit code?

Comment: It compiles fine in Synopsys VCS, too.

Comment: When i run the code in Quartus II it gives me no error, but when i try to simulate the waveforms on ModelSim it gives me the two erros above...

Comment: I'm synthesising the mips processor in VHDL, in the Alu 32 bit block i have to use the alu_1bit block, so I'm compiling the entire MIPS processor, but the other parts are working, only this alu_1bit on ModelSim doesn't works.

Comment: Your code doesn't exhibit the errors as is, there are no non-static expressions using infix operators as actuals. Your question isn't a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) exaample without the ability to replicate the error which needs the entity and architecture pairs for mux4 and full_adder as well as stimuli.  What it sounds like is you're not trying to simulate the fixed code  you've shown, a tool usage issue and not a problem with the fixed VHDL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you realize you didn't post alu_1bit_msb.vhd in your question originally while showing us error messages for it?  The confusion on your audience's part is pardonable. A file name isn't required to bear any relationship to declarations found within.

In any event the fix you put in alu_1bit should also be put in alu_1bit_msb:

```
architecture arch_1 of alu_1bit_msb is
    component full_adder is
    port (
        i_CIN : in std_logic; 
        i_DIN0 : in std_logic; 
        i_DIN1 : in std_logic; 
        o_DOUT : out std_logic; 
        o_COUT : out std_logic); 
    end component;

    component mux4 is
    port(i_SEL : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 
          i_DIN0 : in std_logic; 
          i_DIN1 : in std_logic; 
          i_DIN2 : in std_logic; 
          i_DIN3 : in std_logic; 
          o_DOUT : out std_logic); 
    end component;

    signal w_B : std_logic;
    signal w_C:     std_logic;      -- added
    signal w_D:     std_logic;      -- added
    signal w_OUTFA : std_logic;
    signal w_COUT : std_logic;

begin

    w_B <= i_INV_BIT XOR i_B;

    o_SET <= w_OUTFA;

    w_C <= i_A and i_B;  -- added
    w_D <= i_A or i_B;   -- added

    o_OVERFLOW <= (w_COUT XOR i_CARRY_IN) AND i_OPERATION(1);

    u_1: full_adder port map (i_CIN => i_CARRY_IN,
                                      i_DIN0 => i_A,
                                      i_DIN1 => w_B,
                                      o_DOUT => w_OUTFA,
                                    o_COUT => w_COUT);

    u_2: mux4 port map(
                i_SEL => i_OPERATION,       
                            i_DIN0 => w_C, -- was i_A AND i_B,
                            i_DIN1 => w_D, -- was i_A OR i_B,
                            i_DIN2 => w_OUTFA,
                          i_DIN3 => i_LESS,
                            o_DOUT => o_RESULT);    
end arch_1;
```

Your arch_1 of alu_1bit_msb analyzes (alu_1bit_msb.vhd should compile with vcom).

After that if you have a different problem ask a different question, and please provide an MCVe so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: I should replace the alu_1bit_msb with the code above?

Comment: You should make the changes shown. Add the signal declarations for x_C and x_D. Add the concurrent signal assignments to x_C and x_D and change the actuals to x_C and x_D.  These changes remove the non-static expressions with infix operators from the actuals.

Comment: Ok, i did this and works! Thanks dude! Sorry about the missing MCVe.